# Administrative plan for a company's mail, accounts, etc

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, administration

(I don't know if this is the correct stack btw)

So I've been hired by a very very young company, with only 3 members (I'm the fourth) and everything is still very fresh. These folks have a domain and a webmail service setted, with now 4 email accounts (one for each member).

Since I started 2 new platforms are being used (Cloudflare and Github) but the company is expected to grow so I thought: We can't keep using our address to access to these platforms, if the quantity of employees and services used keeps growing it would be a chaos.

So I have no idea how businesses manage this kind of situations.

For now I thought of using mail aliases like: admin@domain.com or accounts@domain.com or maybe an alias for each platform. Then assign each alias to the users that might need to receive mails from said platform.

**So my concerns are:**

- How much should I specialize these aliases?
- What things should I consider when considering account ownership?
- What is an appropriate way to manage credentials?
- Generally, how are these things planned? (any jucy article or resource?)

For now I thing I should center the answers considering that the company might not grow in size for some time and, in a future, if the taken approach doesn't scale properly then re-think the whole situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach is to use some kind of directory service. If your company have expertise and use services from Microsoft, Active directory (which include LDAP) is the obvious answer. You can use then MS Exchange for mail, groups, etc.

Otherwise you can use Zimbra which will provide you LDAP and mail services. Or build the things from zero with OpenLDAP, postfix, etc.

You can use LDAP/AD for authentication for CLoudflate (as generic SAML). About GitHub - you need Enterprise edition to use LDAP/AD for authentication.

P.S. This subject is huge and your company architect should build/offer the solution.

Comment: oof, I'm the only one that have any kind of technical knowledge and I'm just a CS student ._. 

In conversations with the CEO he speculated that it may pass a year until new people could be incorporated. Since we are only four and there is time, it's feasible for me to tackle this issue, right? At least until a more qualified person can be hired

Comment: @Pau, yes, of course. For the moment you can keep the current situation and do accounts by hand. BTW in case of need you can use MS Teams as chat/meeting program (with personal accounts). But on the moment you become 10-15 or more people you will need kind of centralized solution :) Good luck